# Illegal invocation error in ajax (Jquery 1.7.1)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to post an ajax request using jquery

```
var peName = document.getElementById("peName").value;
     var peSubName = document.getElementById("peSubName").value;
     var peDesc = document.getElementById("peDesc").value;
     var pePrice = document.getElementById("pePrice").value;
     var peCat = document.getElementById("peCat");   
     var pecatId = peCat.options[peCat.selectedIndex].value;
     var radioActive = getRadioValue("proeActive");
     var radioSpicy = getRadioValue("proeSpicy");
     var radioVeg = getRadioValue("proeVeg");
$.post("/product/saveEditProduct",
            {  
                peId    :   peId,
                pecatId :   pecatId,
                peName  :   peName,
                peSubName  : peSubName,
                peDesc : peDesc,
                pePrice : pePrice,
                radioActive : radioActive,
                radioSpicy : radioSpicy,
                radioVeg : radioVeg,
              },
```

but i am getting following error in firebug console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
jQuery.extend.param.add         jquery-1.7.1.js:7601
buildParams             jquery-1.7.1.js:7658
buildParams             jquery-1.7.1.js:7653
buildParams             jquery-1.7.1.js:7653
jQuery.extend.param         jquery-1.7.1.js:7621
jQuery.extend.ajax          jquery-1.7.1.js:7467
jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery-1.7.1.js:7106
editSaveProduct             order-1.0.js:682
```

I am new to jquery and have no idea what is it?

Comment: I think some code is missing there, for instance several braces are missing in the code sample above. Please edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you seem to be missing your function call closure bracket.

```
$.post("/product/saveEditProduct",
    {  
        peId    :   peId,
        pecatId :   pecatId,
        peName  :   peName,
        peSubName  : peSubName,
        peDesc : peDesc,
        pePrice : pePrice,
        radioActive : radioActive,
        radioSpicy : radioSpicy,
        radioVeg : radioVeg,
     });
```

Comment: It's allready commented. and I can't believe it's it (He has `,` so the code continue.)

Comment: i noticed while updating this question that peId we not declared above in this method which was causing this issues. Thanks for your help. var peId = document.getElementById("peId").value;

Answer (score 20):

I'm a novice, but this error happened to me when I did something like the following:

```
// the following will *error*
var element = $("#elementId");
$.post("/foo/bar/", { xxx : element });
```

Anytime you feed `$.post` something other than a `string`, JS errors. i.e., `peId`, `pecatId`, etc. must all be strings, not jQuery objects.